# HTML5 Shiv Not Initializing with Modernizr

Tags: modernizr, html5shiv

I'm running the full development version of Modernizr on my site, and while html5shiv is included in Modernizr, it doesn't seem to be running. If I add html5shiv as a separate script to the page, everything works great. The rest of Modernizr is working fine, too. Do I have to initialize the html5shiv in Modernizr somehow? The docs make it seem like it automatically runs.

Here's the code at the head of my page:

```
<script src="/assets_site/js/head.load.min.js"></script>
<script>
  head.js(
    { modernizr: '/assets_site/js/modernizr.js' },
    { jquery: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' },
    { placeholder: '/assets_site/js/jquery.placeholder.min.js' },
    { response: '/assets_site/js/jquery.response.min.js' }
  );
</script>
```

And the separate html5shiv code that's been working where Modernizr hasn't:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Dumb question, but I'm rather puzzled. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, figured it out. The problem was that I'm a blockhead.

The html5shiv was loading fine in Modernizr, but I also had respond.js set to run inside that conditional IE snippet. When I removed the html5shiv script, I removed respond.js along with it, which caused the layout to go bonkers. I was completely ignoring the media queries part and assumed it was a html5 problem.

Mystery solved (though it's no mystery that I'm a blockhead).

Answer (score 2):

2 things:

1. have you checked that the shiv is included in your
   download? http://modernizr.com/download/
2. where in your document are
       you loading modernizr.js? It may be necessary to load it in the head
        rather than at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say include Modernizr separately from head.js.